# php: my statement always returns true, even when it shouldn't

Tags: php, forms

I have a small problem with some php code and I can't find a way to solve this, does anybody have a solution for this?

```
echo $_REQUEST['id']."<br>";//this echo gives 24
echo $_SESSION['id']."<br>";//this echo gives 2
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && intval($_SESSION['id']) == $row['id']);
        echo "<a href = \"changeProfile.php?\">chenge your profile.</a>"; //this is always showed
```

Comment: The syntax error (that doesn't flag an error) would be obvious if you used `condition action` on one line or used braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon at the end of your control statement:
This is causing it to always "echo" as the next line is not part of that conditional.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && intval($_SESSION['id']) == $row['id'])
    echo "<a href = \"changeProfile.php?\">chenge your profile.</a>";
```

or

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && intval($_SESSION['id']) == $row['id']){
    echo "<a href = \"changeProfile.php?\">chenge your profile.</a>";
}
```

Comment: To avoid ambiguity for other users can you please post the corrected code

Comment: thank you that was indeed the problem, i'll accept your answer as soon i can (which is 3 minutes right now)